# How to normalize the output of a neural network

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, normalization, sigmoid-curve

We have a VGG16 network trained from scratch with a Sigmoid output function.
We have 6 classes and the usual output looks like this:

```
scores': [6.494849458249519e-08, 1.8738395510808914e-06, 3.010111981893715e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8633317947387695]
```

The problem is that the output value is very low in each class, I would like to have a normalized output that sums to 1.0
Thanks

Comment: Don't you have softmax layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sigmoid outputs will each vary between 0 and 1, but if you have $k$ sigmoid units, then the **total** can vary between 0 and $k$. By contrast, a softmax function sums to 1 and has non-negative values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the output being too low, try re-scaling the output. I don't clearly understand what you mean by normed output sum to 1.

However,  *if you want the sum of output to be 1*,  one possible way is considering **log-likelihood** or **log-it** transformation. The log function takes into account properly the negative indices in powers of 10.